# Why is this JavaScript function not working?

Tags: javascript, function, button, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am working with bootstrap and attempting to create a button in tab 1 which "activates" (switches to) tab 2.

Here's my code:

HTML navigation tabs:

```
    <ul id="pageSwitcher" class="nav nav-tabs" style="width:100%;">
      <li><a href="#page1" data-toggle="tab">Page One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2" data-toggle="tab">Page Two</a></li>
    </ul>
```

HTML tab content:

```
<div class="tab-content" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="page1">
        <button type="button" onclick="showPageTwo();">Proceed to page 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="page2">
        <p>Page 2 content here!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});

function showPageTwo() {
    $('#pageSwitcher li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
}

</script>
```

Anyone willing to provide some insight as to where exactly I'm going wrong? I've copied several examples almost exactly... **clicking on the tabs themselves works fine**, I just can't seem to make a button at the bottom of page 1 that activates page 2.

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: Syntax error in your .click()... see below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One: bad form, inline onclick call... you don't need it, get rid of it:

```
        <button type="button">Proceed to page 2</button>
```

Two: you have two JS errors. You didn't close your .click() function, and you're trying to trigger the first tab with the specifier of li:eq(0)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        // ALSO, you were missing a closing paren, here!
    });

    //two issues ... onclick inside your button is trying to access
    // your function before it's available... inline js like that, bad idea anyhow
    // so hook into it inside your DOM ready code here anyhow.

    var showPageTwo = function() {
        // secondly, you're looking at the wrong item!
        // li:eq(0) means "look at the first li in the array of li"
        $('#pageSwitcher li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
    };

    $(".tab-content").on("click","#page1 button", showPageTwo);
});
```

See this jsFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/Xr9eT/

Comment: Perfect! +1 for actually explaining my mistakes. Now I understand. Thank you! Also: derp @ targetting the wrong li element... lol!

Comment: I would actually suggest looking at @adeneo's example for using .trigger() rather than just .tab('show'), unless the Bootstrap docs specifically call out using it that way. .trigger() should kick off any on-event bubbles that other elements might be waiting for, so if you see anything strange happening, try that method to see if it resolves any outliers for you.

Answer (score 1):

Give your button an ID :

```
<div class="tab-content" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="page1">
        <button type="button" id="myButton">Proceed to page 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="page2">
        <p>Page 2 content here!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and just trigger a click on the right anchor, bootstrap does the rest :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTab a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: We all missed the most obvious bug... he doesn't close his paren after the (myTab a).click()...

Comment: @mori57 - Good eye, did'nt notice that at all.

Comment: Nor did I, until I was trying to jsFiddle it and saw something weird in the console. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use specific code for your button, but generic event-driven process:

- you should add an attribute to your button to specify towards which page it will redirect

- then attach a click event

- attach click event to tabs to do the same

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btn" gotoPage="#page2">Proceed to page 2</button>
```

JS to process tab switching:

```
function showPage(pageId){
    $('.tab-pane').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).hide();
    }); 
    $(pageId).show();
    $(pageId).addClass('active');
 }
```

(Not sure you need to use show or hide functions if you CSS manages thats thanks to active class)

Then for your button:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var destPage = $(this).attr('gotoPage');
    showPage(destPage);
});
```

For tabs:

```
$('#pageSwitcher a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        showPage($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

And you can load page one at startup, if needed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showPage("#page1");    // default: load page 1
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DSbrj/1/

Answer (score -1):

showPageTwo() should be declared outside of the document.ready() call.